# gitolite emailprefix GL_REPO not expanded

Tags: hook, gitolite

I am using gitolite v2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

The GL_REPO variable does not get expanded for emailprefix.

In my gitolite.conf file I have this:

```
repo @all
    config hooks.mailinglist = xxx@somewhere
    config hooks.emailprefix = "[%GL_REPO] "
    config hooks.emailmaxlines = 1000

...
repo testing
    RW+ = @all
```

I am getting email when I push changes to the testing repo, but the subject line looks like this:

```
[%GL_REPO] branch master updated.
```

Is there a typo in my configuration, a setting I missed, or is this a problem in v2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution of the variable `GL_REPO` in `gitolite.conf` file is only documented in gitolite v3 (or 'g3') pages:

- [Admin conf](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#admin-conf)
- ["git-config" keys and values](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config.html)
- [the `conf/gitolite.conf` file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf)

For g2 (gitolite V2.x), it is only mentioned (and expanded) for **[gitolite hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html#admin_environment_variables_available_to_hooks_)**.

Upgrading to v3 is therefore the way to go, since it won't affect any of your existing bare repos: see [the migration page](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/migr.html).